# How to import CSV files to SQLite3 with python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlite, sqlalchemy

This is my code.

```
import sqlite3
import pandas

db = sqlite3.connect('testdb.db')

df = pandas.read_csv('testcsv.csv')
df.to_sql('testTable', 'db', if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I got the last two lines of code from another article on stackoverflow, but it doesn't work for me. This is the error I get, even after I installed sqlalchemy, because it complained that it wasn't installed.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/pitye/PycharmProjects/gradeCalcV2/venv/sqlite.py", line 7, in <module>
    df.to_sql('testTable', 'db', if_exists='append', index=False)
  File "C:\Users\pitye\PycharmProjects\gradeCalcV2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py", line 2663, in to_sql
    method=method,
  File "C:\Users\pitye\PycharmProjects\gradeCalcV2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 503, in to_sql
    pandas_sql = pandasSQL_builder(con, schema=schema)
  File "C:\Users\pitye\PycharmProjects\gradeCalcV2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 577, in pandasSQL_builder
    con = _engine_builder(con)
  File "C:\Users\pitye\PycharmProjects\gradeCalcV2\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\io\sql.py", line 564, in _engine_builder
    con = sqlalchemy.create_engine(con)
  File "C:\Users\pitye\PycharmProjects\gradeCalcV2\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\__init__.py", line 479, in create_engine
    return strategy.create(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\pitye\PycharmProjects\gradeCalcV2\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\strategies.py", line 54, in create
    u = url.make_url(name_or_url)
  File "C:\Users\pitye\PycharmProjects\gradeCalcV2\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 229, in make_url
    return _parse_rfc1738_args(name_or_url)
  File "C:\Users\pitye\PycharmProjects\gradeCalcV2\venv\lib\site-packages\sqlalchemy\engine\url.py", line 291, in _parse_rfc1738_args
    "Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string '%s'" % name
sqlalchemy.exc.ArgumentError: Could not parse rfc1738 URL from string 'db'
```

I just want to create a table from a CSV file in SQLite. Is this even the right way of doing it, or am I waaay off?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you just have to replace

`df.to_sql('testTable', 'db', if_exists='append', index=False)`

With

`df.to_sql('testTable', db, if_exists='append', index=False)`